# How to prevent direct access to cloudfront domain name and instead only via custom domain

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've set up a static site on AWS with route 53, ACM, cloudfront and s3. However although I can prevent direct access to the bucket's generated domain name via a bucket policy so that access is only via my custom domain eg `www.example.com` I'm not sure how to do this for cloudfront and currently the website can be accessed via a cloudfront domain name  eg `23324sdfff.cloudfront.net`

Is there a way to prevent access to the website via the cloudfront domain name so that traffic can only access the site directly via `www.example.com`?

Answer (score 1):

I think you could achieve that using [Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html).

Specifically you could create a function for [viewer-request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-edge.html). The function would inspect the request and then decide if to allow or deny it.

Sadly, I don't have concrete example addressing your specific use-case. But AWS docs provide a number of [examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-access-request-body-examples) that could be useful to you.

Maybe,there is an easier way not involving the lambda, but at present I'm not aware of such a possibility.

Comment: Thanks that helps at least to know I probably haven't missed anything obvious. I presume without preventing direct access that a search engine could index it twice, once via a custom domain and the second time via the cloudfront domain?

Comment: @Yunti Not sure about the search engine behavior in this case. I think that if you don't advertise your cloudfront url on other website, your custom domain would be only used.